# Does staticmethod annotation works in python?

Tags: python, static-methods

A static method has to be called only by the class. Am I right ?. I came across the below snippet from geeksforgeeks.

```
  from datetime import date

  class Person:
     def __init__(self, name, age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age

     # a class method to create a Person object by birth year.
     @classmethod
     def fromBirthYear(cls, name, year):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - year)

     # a static method to check if a Person is adult or not.
     @staticmethod
     def isAdult(age):
        return age > 18

     # can a method annotated with staticmethod be called through self   
     def IsAdultorNot(self):
         return self.isAdult(age)


     person1 = Person('mayank', 21)
     person2 = Person.fromBirthYear('mayank', 1996)

     print(person1.age)
     print(person2.age)
     # print the result

     # the below statement should raise an error isn't it ?. 
     print(person2.isAdult(22))
```

Just out of curiosity, I tried calling the method annotated with staticmethod using an instance of a class and the class itself. Surprisingly, I got the result from both ways.

Should there be an error while calling a static function through an object? And `isAdult` is a static method, can it be called through `self` operator?

Comment: Same as in C++. You can call a static function using an instance. The compiler will "interpret" that as if you were using the class of the instance (with only difference from your case being that in Python this decision takes place during runtime).

Comment: Even in the runtime, I didn't get any kind of errors. The program ran smoothly.

Comment: I didn't say you should be getting errors, I said **you shouldn't** be getting errors!

Comment: Errors hasn't, there should be some information saying 'This is a static method'. Instead, I didn't get any. Then what's the point of annotating a method with 'staticmethod'. Even in C++, as you said during runtime, you would get some information saying, 'you are calling a static method through an object' which is not the case in python.